# how do i make source devel/setup.bash permanent

Tags: ros, setup.bash

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Every time i open a new terminal i have to type the following to set directories

```
 $ ~/catkin_ws/ source 
 $  source devel/setup.bash
```

and for once i forget to set it takes me a while to detect.

I wanna make this change permanent so i could skip this step

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/196452/how-do-i-make-source-devel/setup.bash-permanent/) by [Nouman Tahir](https://answers.ros.org/users/20072/nouman-tahir/) on ROS Answers with karma: 35 on 2014-11-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

you need to source  in `.bashrc` file.

---

open .bashrc file by `gedit .bashrc`
add line `source /FULL...PATH../devel/setup.bash` at the end

---

Originally posted by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) with karma: 3034 on 2014-11-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3